# Can I transfer my saved game between platforms?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've been playing KSP on a Mac, but I'd like to transfer all my save data over to a Windows PC. Is this possible? If so, where are the files and what do I need to transfer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your VAB and ship files should be in `~/Library/Application Support/KSP_osx/saves/[YourSave]/ships/` on OS X.

The location of the real Library folder is a bit different on Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8), you will need to use Finder to get to it.

- Select "Go" (Or press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) from the system menu
- Then select on "Go to Folder" (skip this step is you used the keyboard shortcut)
- Type in "~/Library/Application Support" and then "Go."

On Windows, the same files should be in the folder at `%KSP_ROOT_Directory%\saves\...`

Comment: Where is ` %KSP_ROOT_Directory%`?

Comment: Wherever you installed KSP.

Comment: I installed it via Steam. What absolute path does that expand to for KSP installed via Steam on Windows?

Comment: `...\Steam\SteamApps\Common\Kerbal Space Program`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is actually fairly easy.  All of your save data is stored in plain text files as a subdirectory of the `saves` folder in the main KSP folder.  Each save game has its own folder, which includes subdirectories for VAB and hanger ships.  Simply copy the desired folders (be it the entire save or just a few `.craft` files) to the new install location.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to note if you have KSP on Steam on OS X, here's where the ship saves live:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Kerbal Space Program/saves/<save name>/Ships/
```

Note the spaces in the path.

Answer (score 3):

You can even put the files in something like dropbox and then make aliases/shortcuts from the save game directory and have them shared between computers.  Just don't play it in more than one place at a time.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac using the GOG-Version of the game and using the GOG GalaxyClient the save files are actually in the *.app Application-File itself. Locate KSP in the Finder and do a Right-Click > Show Package Contents and navigate to `Contents/Resources/game/saves`.